# Problem with transaction using Paypal Web API-s in production

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have setup paypal web api to my website.
I am trying to make transaction with sandbox and it works perfectly, when I switch to production it shows me error 400.

This is the error that is displayed when I want to make a buy.

```
        polyfills.js:3 Uncaught Error: Payment could not be executed
            at handleExecuteError (button.js:3658)
            at _loop (promise.js:176)
            at ZalgoPromise._proto.dispatch (promise.js:153)
            at ZalgoPromise._proto.reject (promise.js:127)
            at _loop (promise.js:171)
            at ZalgoPromise._proto.dispatch (promise.js:153)
            at ZalgoPromise._proto.reject (promise.js:127)
            at _loop (promise.js:188)
            at ZalgoPromise._proto.dispatch (promise.js:153)
            at ZalgoPromise._proto.resolve (promise.js:96)
            at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.<computed> [as postrobot_message_response] (types.js:121)
            at receiveMessage (index.js:114)
            at messageListener (index.js:140)
            at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
            at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
            at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:3)
            at p (polyfills.js:2)
            at v (polyfills.js:2)


        POST https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/payment/PAYID-LVWNUDI9DU43623DF981944G/execute 400


        {ack: "contingency", contingency: "TRANSACTION_REFUSED", meta: {calc: "71b2e65ea74e9",…},…}
        ack: "contingency"
        contingency: "TRANSACTION_REFUSED"
        meta: {calc: "71b2e65ea74e9",…}
        server: "4QAuqKwxrUdYdGi84SEU03FmXzRw0XF3yfCRA7dd6kswcXfv-mbr7oWfE9GyjiMg0YtEGm7S_j27rzW5UW4X0OjO56H1b-5gqiDNMSVDGd2a-jUaTT0gRldo0-flg_LVqm47ZoQvZRNsBnpasVa1uKx4pzBUWuYyOwC0Je0KQf_4ITFcRzJNzwF2D0-oDORPVQ3VK3OURAyHvSnU0G64GoZlPoIqjWoJkV2itzWms1eXzGYQ3JR_x96cCrNLzgzm2OZ6d7eJ57e"
```

Comment: If anything goes wrong in the data given, paypal api will return a 400 - Bad request error. there are several things that can cause the (HTTP 400 - Bad Request). just try to catch the api exception and see the details. because PayPal returns detailed data on every exception (except 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)